# Symfony 1 propel - how to get an object by ID without DB select like retrieveByPK

Tags: orm, symfony1, propel

I need to set Channel object to ChannelMedia. 
I don't have Channel object, I've got ID instead.
I could use ChannelPeer static method, retrieveByPK, but that makes Select to DB only to get the object.

How do I achieve that?

Check below code:

```
    $channel = ChannelPeer::retrieveByPK($channelID);
    $channel_media = new ChannelMedia();
    $channel_media->setMedia($this->object);

    // How to pass ID here?
    // Alternatively, how to create object from $channelID without DB conn?
    $channel_media->setChannel($channel);
    $channel_media->setStatus(3);
    $channel_media->save();
```

Comment: If you can help it, move away from Peer classes, use ActiveQuery instead, i.e. `$channel - ChannelQuery::create()findPk($channelID);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ChannelMedia` class should have a `setChannelId()` method. You could use that to set the channel ID, thus avoiding the need to make an extra call to the DB.

```
$channel_media = new ChannelMedia();
$channel_media->setMedia($this->object);
$channel_media->setChannelId($channelID);
$channel_media->setStatus(3);
$channel_media->save();
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize that I've got such a method. So simple :)